# different parameters in each branch in jenkins multibranch declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins scripted pipeline in a multibranch job.

There is a parameter that is only supposed to be available in the trunk, not in any of the branches of the multibranch job.

Currently with scripted pipeline this is easy to do (inside a shared library or directly on Jenkinsfile):

```
def jobParams = [
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'param1', name: 'param1')
]

if (whateverCondition) {
    jobParams.add(booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'param2', name: 'param2'))
}

properties([
        parameters(jobParams)
])
```

I am currently trying to migrate to jenkins declarative syntax, but i don't see a simple way to create a parameter that is only available in some conditions (i know i can ignore it, but i don't really want it to show it at all).

The only solution so far is to move the pipeline to a shared library also (possible since [Declarative 1.2](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines)). I don't like this solution because the entire pipeline must be replicated, which seem a bit too extreme just for one line.

```
if (whateverCondition) {
    pipeline {
      agent any
      parameters {
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'param1', name: 'param1')
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'param2', name: 'param2')
      }
    (...)
    }
} else {
    pipeline {
      agent any
      parameters {
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'param1', name: 'param1')
      }
    (...)
    }
```

}

Is there a way i can extract just the part of parameter definition of the declarative pipeline to a global variable of a shared library or something?

Thanks in advance for any help!